Microsoft visual studio installer project, ошибка в mscorlib.dll
Сборка начата в 23:40...
------ Starting pre-build validation for project 'Setup' ------ 
ERROR: Unable to find file 'normnfkc.nlp' of multi-file assembly 'mscorlib.dll'
ERROR: Unable to find file 'normnfkd.nlp' of multi-file assembly 'mscorlib.dll'
ERROR: Unable to find file 'normnfd.nlp' of multi-file assembly 'mscorlib.dll'
ERROR: Unable to find file 'normnfc.nlp' of multi-file assembly 'mscorlib.dll'
ERROR: Unable to find file 'normidna.nlp' of multi-file assembly 'mscorlib.dll'
------ Pre-build validation for project 'Setup' completed ------
1>------ Сборка начата: проект: Setup, Конфигурация: Release ------
========== Сборка: успешно выполнено — 0 , со сбоем — 1, в актуальном состоянии — 1, пропущено — 0 ==========
========== Сборка завершено в 23:40 и заняло 00,655 с ==========

я знаю где они хранятся, но как указать их, это уже проблема
я переустанавливал .net framework, и использовал другие установщики, но ничего не помогало
